# Merge two files depending on range using awk

Tags: awk

I have a file (let's call it main.txt) where the 1st column contains some numbers (2, 4, 8, 15).

```
2 OtherData
4 OtherData
8 OtherData
15 OtherData
```

Also, I have other file mapping.txt. I want to compare each value from main.txt (2, 4, 8, 15) with first 2 columns of mapping file.

The 1st column is a minimum allowed value, the 2nd is a maximum.

```
1 4      1stType
5 9      2ndType
10 14    3rdType
15 99    4thType
100 1000 5thType
```

How can I get a result like this using **awk**?

```
2 OtherData  1stType   # 1 <= 2 <= 4
4 OtherData  1stType   # 1 <= 4 <= 4
8 OtherData  2ndType   # 5 <= 8 <= 9
15 OtherData 4thType   # 15 <= 15 <= 100
```

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples only in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  ++count
  start[count]=$1
  end[count]=$2
  value[count]=$NF
  next
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    if($1>=start[i] && $1<=end[i]){
       print $0,value[i]
    }
  }
}
'  Input_file2  Input_file1  |  column -t
```

Output will be as follows.

```
2   OtherData  1stType
4   OtherData  1stType
8   OtherData  2ndType
15  OtherData  4thType
```

Answer (score 2):

A shorter `awk` solution that loops through range and store mapping in an array:

```
awk 'NR == FNR {
   for (i=$1; i<=$2; i++)
      map[i] = $3
   next
}
$1 in map {
   print $0, map[$1]
}' mapping.txt main.txt
```

```
2 OtherData 1stType
4 OtherData 1stType
8 OtherData 2ndType
15 OtherData 4thType
```

---

Alternative `awk`:

```
awk 'NR == FNR {
   map[$1,$2] = $3
   next
}
{
   for (i in map) {
      split(i, a, SUBSEP)
      if ($1 >= a[1] && $1 <= a[2]) {
         print $0, map[i]
         next
      }
   }
}' mapping.txt main.txt
```